# sshfs 'no such file' error

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I'm trying to use sshfs to share a folder between two of my computers.

I can ssh from the server, and see the folder I want to share.  However, when I run sshfs, I get:

```
david@desktop2:~$sshfs desktop1:~/folder/ ~/Documents/folder/
desktop1:~/folder/: No such file or directory
```

Desktop2 is running 11.10.  Desktop1 is running 10.04.

I ssh from desktop2 to desktop1 and view the folder, and I can use scp to copy a file from one computer to another.

What do I need to do differently for this to work?

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/199162/sshfs-no-such-file-or-directory/856441

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`~` is expanded by the shell. Paths are relative on `sshfs`, you are currently asking to mount `/home/someuser/~/folder` from machine `desktop1`.

Drop the `~/` part and `sshfs` should find the remote folder relative to the home directory:

```
sshfs desktop1:folder/ ~/Documents/folder/
```