# sshfs - No such file or directory

Tags: sshfs

I'm trying to mount a folder over ssh using sshfs.  Evertime I do so I get the error

```
No such file or directory
```

My terminal:

```
user@computer:~$ sshfs admin@server.com:/volume1/somedir ~/mnt/somedir
admin@server.com's password: 
admin@server.com:/volume1/somedir: No such file or directory
```

It returns the directory listing, as expected if I try:

```
ssh admin@server.com ls /volume1/somedir
```

This is Ubuntu 12.04 connecting to a Synology NAS with DS4.1

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you try to mount something in `~/` see  http://askubuntu.com/questions/99997/sshfs-no-such-file-error

Comment: In Ubuntu, after typing the first part `sshfs admin@server.com:`, you can press `tab` and it will automatically find the home directory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So aparently when connecting to sftp on a Synology, / is the list of shares.  So I just have to do:

```
sshfs admin@server.com:/somedir ~/mnt/somedir
```

Comment: Same problem with a Synology server.  Your solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
sshfs admin@server.com:/remotedir ~/mnt/localdir
```

where remotedir is dir you normally specify after volume1

or

```
sshfs admin@server.com:/ ~/mnt/localdir
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on connecting to a VM in a Debian xen host where I have forwarded every VM ssh port to another port.

All paths were correct, when testing with `ssh admin@server.com ls`. 
In the end, I noticed, that I mixed up the ports, because I had set a rule to use a certain port in my

```
~/.ssh/config
```

that was not used when trying via `sshfs`

so better add the port to both commands, when testing with

```
ssh -p<someport> admin@server.com ls /volume1/somedir
sshfs -p<someport> admin@server.com:/volume1/somedir ~/mnt/somedir
```